# Authentication Microsoft Graph API with accesstoken/refresh token

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I'm trying to make a datacollector that connects to a big number of customer tenants to collect their secure score data through the Microsoft GraphApi.

Access to the customer tenants will be possible through the use of a Multi-Customer application registration in a CSPTenant("Partner-Managed Application"). This is an application that is Pre-consented in all CSPCustomers tenants automatically and will give user access through delegated admin in these tenants from a user account in the CSPTenant.

I must use User + Application(delegated permissions) with MFA to access the customer tenants.

The plan is to make a ASP.NET Core site that a user in the CSPTenant can log in to with MFA and catch the refresh token , store it somewhere(KeyVault) and use it on a schedule to get accesstokens that allows access to the different customer tenants to read data from Microsoft Graph API without a user being present for as long as the refresh token allows it(90 days I believe).

Making the ASP.NET Core site to catch a refresh token seems easy, but then what? What flow do I use, on-behalf of?

Any samples available for something like this?

Libraries to handle accesstoken refresh with the refresh token automatically?

With the refresh token from the CSPsite, how do I get accesstokens valid for the different customer tenants Graph API?

**UPDATE to hopefully make it easier to understand**

- ASP.NET Core site with Azure AD MFA user login to CSPTenant(supplier)
- Grab and store refresh token from user login
- Use refresh token to get short lived accesstoken to access Microsoft Graph API and extract customer data from every CSPcustomer tenants on a schedule without user interaction after the initial login.
- User account used to login and get refresh token has delegated admin in all customer tenants, the application registration in CSPTenant is auto admin consented to in all customer tenants.

Comment: Is your application a single-page application?

Comment: Hi! No, it is server side, confidential client with app secret.

Comment: If your application is user interactive login then you can use the Authentication code flow where you can get the access token and refresh token. If you are creating a daemon application then you need to have app secret and which would be client crediential flow and you won't get any refresh token in this flow. Please check this document to understand more on which flow you would like to choose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows